# How to user Scanner check if a Zip file compressed by CSV or other type of files in JAVA?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, zipinputstream

I am trying to use Scanner read ZipInputStream line by line, below is the code i have

```
                    ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(bodyPartEntity.getInputStream());
                    inputStream.getNextEntry();
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        log.info(sc.nextLine());
                    }
```

and it works fine.

But I have a question, what if a user compressed an image or different type of files (not CSV) as a Zip. Is there a way that I can check that so I can throw an exception for it? Also, is there a way to read `next file`?

For now, if I compressed multiple files, I'm only able to read one. And then `sc.hasNextLine()` will be equal to false.

Anyway, I can read the next file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should loop over your zip file like this:

```
ZipEntry entry;
while((entry = inputStream.getNextEntry())!=null){
  // do your logic here...
  // for example: entry.getName()
}
```

For the file type, you could use something like this, inside of while loop:

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mtft = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mimeType = mtft.getContentType(entry.getName());
System.out.println(entry.getName()+" type: "+ mimeType);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to loop over your zip, as it was suggested before.

Then you need to check the type of the file with [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). I think this is the best library if you need to determine the type of the file. It can detect filetype from file extension and file content as well. To use file content is the safest solution, and it fits best for your scenario (stream).

See more info here:

- [description of Tika detector interface](https://tika.apache.org/1.21/detection.html)
- [API](https://tika.apache.org/1.21/api/org/apache/tika/detect/Detector.html)
- [example, how to use it](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-tika)